# Query string not being passed to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, post, get, parameters

I have what should be a relatively simple form in Rails that I'm using to send an email for two different previews, a desktop preview and a mobile preview.

```
<form id="email-form" role="form" action="<%= action_name == 'desktop_preview' ? email_preview_newsletter_path(@newsletter) : email_preview_newsletter_path(@newsletter, mobile: 'true') %>">
    <label for="email_address">Email</label>
    <input type="email" id="email_address" name="email_address" value="<%= params[:email_address] %>" placeholder="PLEASE ENTER EMAIL">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary"></input>
</form>
```

Right now I have it setup so that both previews get sent to the same endpoint, '/email_preview', but in the case of the mobile_preview I want to pass in a 'mobile' query string so that it ends up looking like this:

'/email_preview?mobile=true'

When I inspect the form on the page everything looks in order, however when it gets passed to the controller the 'mobile' part of the query string disappears and only the 'email_address' exists.

I suppose I could pass in the mobile value as a hidden field, but something about that just doesn't feel right to me. What is the best way to setup this form so that both the 'mobile' and 'email_address' key value pairs are passed as query strings when sent to the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the process of writing out this question I realized exactly what the problem was:

I had the form setup as a GET request as opposed to a POST request.

This was causing any pre-established query strings to get erased in the process of setting up the GET params being defined in the form (in this case, the 'email_address' param). Changing the form from GET to POST, (i.e. form method="POST")

Took care of this issue. Please note that if you are going to manually setup a form like this in rails then you also need to explicitly take care of the csrf token. This can be done by inserting the following input with the helper method into your form:

input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="<%=form_authenticity_token%>"